# LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C09044E, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v2580 (first time using ldap)

Tags: java, spring, ldap, spring-ldap, spring-security-ldap

I am having problem with ldap on spring, I know what that error means but idk what i am doing wrong in the config of the connection

this is my application.properties :

```
spring.ldap.urls=ldap://***
spring.ldap.base=OU=Account,DC=company,DC=lan
spring.ldap.username=CN=Intranet company
spring.ldap.password=pswd
```

The password are good and username too but maybe my base is false? can anyone help me plz?

and here is what i try to do

```
@Autowired
private LdapTemplate ldapTemplate;
```

```
System.out.println( ldapTemplate.search(
        "OU=Account,DC=company,DC=lan",
        "cn=" + account.username ,
                (AttributesMapper<String>) attrs -> (String) attrs.get("sAMAccountName").get()));
```

I just try to connect to the active directory and discover how it works

Comment: code looks kinda okay, but it is impossible to help without some more error messages, knowing your AD structure, more of your program etc.

Comment: did you look at some ldap java tutorials/help online?

Comment: the error is saying invalid credentials (https://community.arubanetworks.com/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?MID=40296)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message makes it clear that you're using Active Directory. So I'm pretty sure this is the problem:

```
spring.ldap.username=CN=Intranet company
```

I don't think Active Directory likes that format for the username. It either has to be:

- The full DN (`CN=Intranet company,OU=Account,DC=company,DC=lan`), or
- The plain username (`sAMAccountName` attribute), or
- `DOMAIN\username` if the user is not on the domain you're connecting to, or
- The `userPrincipalName` (e.g. `username@company.lan`).

Comment: thanks it was the problem